# AWS Elastic beanstalk instance change Node js version 14 to 16 there is option but disabled?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[
I'm working on deploying my application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I've noticed that platform versions 14 to 16 seem to be disabled or unavailable in my AWS region. I need to use one of these specific versions for my project.

What could be the reasons for these platform versions being disabled in certain regions?
Is there a way to enable or access these versions?
If not, what are my alternatives for deploying my application with the required version?
I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to work with these platform versions or find alternatives. Thanks in advance!

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OALDJ.png)

I read Blogs but not found any exect Solution if you have any let me know.

Answer (score 0):

AWS doesn't give the exact reason for retirement of platform branchs. [You can read more info here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-support-policy.html). In the case of nodejs version 14 to 16, we can think that the motivation is to follow [the official end of support](https://nodejs.dev/fr/about/releases/).

Nevertheless, in AWS ElasticBeanstalk, you can run any application you want, if you choose [the Docker platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html). I would advise to create a container with the specific nodejs version you need ; then to create a new environment based on the Docker Platform; and finally run your app. In this way you will adapt you infrastructure without huge changes.

Comment: Was this answer helpfull ?